# Is it possible to repeat an array?

Tags: f#

I need to add 1 to each element in an array, and if it goes out of range, I need to start over.

```
let arr = [| 1; 2; 3 |]

for i = 0 to Array.length arr - 1 do

    arr.[i] <- arr.[i] + 1
    printfn "i %A" (arr.[i])
```

I want to add 5 points to the array, so that it iterates over the array and gives one point in each element, so the array would partially be [| 2; 3; 4 |] and iterate through the array again and end up being arr = [| 3; 4; 4 |]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can calculate exactly how much you should add to each element of array. So you can solve the problem by going through the array in only one time.

```
let addPoints arr points =
    let len = arr |> Array.length
    let added = points / len
    let extraCount = points % len
    arr
    |> Array.mapi (fun i x ->
        if i < extraCount then x + added + 1
        else x + added)

addPoints [| 1; 2; 3 |] 5
|> printfn "%A" // [|3; 4; 4|]
```

Mutating the array or not, it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than mutating the array, a more idiomatic F# approach is to create a new array with the newly calculated results. You can use the built-in `Array.map` function to do apply the same transformation to each element of the array. To increment all by one, you can write:

```
let arr = [| 1; 2; 3 |]
arr |> Array.map (fun v -> v + 1)
```

If you want to restrict the maximal value to `4`, you'll need to do that in the body of the function, i.e. `v + 1`. To make it easier to do this repeatedly, it's helpful to define a function.

```
let step arr = 
  arr |> Array.map (fun v -> min 4 (v + 1))
```

Here, `step` is a function you can call to do one step of the transformation. `min 4 (v + 1)` ensures that when `v + 1` is more than 4, you get just 4 as the result. Now you can run `step` repeatedly using `|>`:

```
let arr1 = arr |> step
let arr2 = arr |> step |> step
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @TomasPetricek in that the way to go should be to create new arrays using map. However, if you *must* mutate the array, the following loop-based approach should work just fine:

```
let incArrayElements n (a : _ []) =
    let rec loop k i =
        if k > 0 then
            a.[i] <- a.[i] + 1
            let ii = i + 1
            if ii >= a.Length then 0 else ii
            |> loop (k - 1)
    if n > 0 then loop n 0
```

If required, this can also be easily modified to include a parameter for the starting index.